# Password encryption in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC and I want to encrypt the password that gets saved in dB, I had a look into other threads and they suggest going with MD5.  Is it a good practice to go with MD5 or is there any other method in Spring to achieve it?

Comment: if you are using spring-security you can use spring security password encoders and also can implements your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify if you are looking for Spring Security or Spring MVC. Your question title is ""Password encryption in "Spring MVC" whereas you have tagged the question for Spring Security.

Spring security suggests to use the following
**org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder**

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/core-services.html#core-services-password-encoding

Comment: I am looking for password encryption in Spring Security

Comment: Great, I have shared the relevant link from Spring reference pages. If you need any help add a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to encode your password, in order to do that you will need to create a bean of this class.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

And while registering (saving new user to database) your user, you can auto wire `PasswordEncoder` and call `encode` method to encode your password

```
@Autowired PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public User registerUser(User user){
   // other logic

   String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
   user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);

   //logic to save the user to DB
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I cannot understand, if I encrypted password by this way how the password can match when I trying to login ? Because if I'm not wrong 'BCryptPasswordEncoder' all time generating different value.By the way I'm new to Spring :)

Comment: When you are trying to login and if you are passing password to login method as a simple text, then you will need to call again the encode method on the password user have provided while logging and then compare

Answer (score 1):

Don't use MD5, the problem with MD5 hashing is that it is relatively quick to do and if someone gets hold of the hashes they can brute force it pretty easily. There are also rainbow tables which are lists of passwords with their associated MD5 hashes.

As @Jan Nielsen suggests, BCrypt is far superior. I personally use PBKDF2. Both these approaches work by using a random salt while generating the hash. In the database you store the salt and the hashed password. I like to go one step further and also store the number of iterations that was used to create the hash.

Here is a good blog on password encryption that covers the details in more depth with code samples. https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 0):

No; use [BCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) -- available in Spring with `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.